# Basic limit question

Tags: limits

I was solving this limit that seemed simple enough to me and yet the following way to go about it is wrong and I'd just like to get a better understanding as to why:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} (\sqrt{x^2+2x+1}-x)
= \lim_{x\to \infty}(|x|\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}-x)
= \lim_{x\to \infty}(x-x)
=0$$

But the actual limit is 1, which we can obtain by rewriting $x^2+2x+1$ as $(x+1)^2$ and taking the root. We then have $|x+1|-x=1$ (as limit is x to infinity)

What am I missing ?

Comment: you cannot take the limit of that square root first and leave the others untouched. Think $\lim x+1-x$ for a simpler example, if you factor $x+1-x = x(1+\frac{1}{x})-x$, taking the limit of the bracket but not the rest, you would conclude the limit being $0$ which is just wrong.

Comment: It's really important when taking limits that you can *NEVER* take the limit of one instance of $x$ first and then take the limit of the other instance later.  It just plain does NOT work.  As $x> 0$ you could continue this with $|x|\sqrt{1+\frac 2x+\frac 1{x^2}} -x= x(\sqrt{1+\frac 2x + \frac 1{x^2} -1)$ which... well it becomes a $\infinity \times 0 = ????$ issue which can be resolved ... um, by Dennis Marx's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I gues a problem occurs at

$\lim_{x\to \infty}(|x|\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}-x)$ since the limit boils down to the undefined expression "$\infty - \infty$", which is erroneosly interpreted as 0.

Using the rule of L'Hospital and considering only positive valuer for $x$ (since you anyway consider the limiting case) this can be solved as

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\lim_{x\to \infty}\,x\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}-x = \lim_{x\to \infty} x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}} - 1\right) = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}} - 1}{\frac{1}{x}}\\
&= \lim_{x\to \infty}\, \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \overset{L'Hospital}{=}\lim_{x\to \infty}\, \frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{g^{\prime}(x)} = \lim_{x\to \infty}\,x\frac{1+x}{x+x^{2}} = \lim_{x\to \infty}\,x\frac{1+x}{x(1+x)} = 1
\end{split}
\end{equation}